# How to interpret differences in VIF and condition number?

Tags: multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor, condition-number

In my present data, the Variance Inflation Factors suggest lack of substential multicolliniearity (<1,7). However, the condition number of 28 is almost at the critical value of 30.

How do I interpret these confusing results? What may cause the difference?

It has been suggested elsewhere that the difference can be eliminated by mean-centering. Though Belsley 1984 demonstrated that this technique does not solve but only mask collinearity problems.

---

Belsley (1984), Demeaning Conditioning Diagnostics through Centering, The American Statistician , 38 (2), pp. 73-77

Comment: If it is less than 30, you need not worry

Comment: Well, from what I read the rule of thumb says that collinearity starts to be a concern at 15 and a serious problem at 30.

Answer (score 1):

The paper is very confusing. I recommend just ignoring VIF, which is based on a common misconception that collinearity is a problem related to statistical estimation or modeling, not numerical linear algebra.

The condition number is the correct estimate of numerical collinearity problems. It says that if you try to estimate such a regression problem, you're going to lose $\log_{10}(2) \approx 1.45$ digits of accuracy.

On the other hand, you probably shouldn't be solving linear regressions like that anyways.

Comment: can you provide a source for your interpretation of the condition number as the number of digits lost when solving via direct inversion+matvec?

Comment: (I ask because according to Wikipedia <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number>, it is actually the base ten log of the condition number which gives digit loss, and there is no mention of matrix inversion versus direct linear system solves.)

Comment: @JohnMadden You're correct, and I've edited the post to reflect that.